# How do you link to a external anchor link in angular?

Tags: angularjs

Currently, I'm linking to a specific sections within my angular view page `landing.html`. I want to link to the same sections from my angular view page `faq.html`. Can someone assist me on how to accomplish this?

PS I'am using Angular 1.5.8

```
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown navbar-user">
    <a onclick="$('#innerScrollableContent').animate({ scrollTop: $('#engine').offset().top}, 'slow');">

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a master view then add the common codes as you mentioned in the master html.

Then load the other pages into that view.

Or use ng-view to load these views to your page.

otherwise create a template and call that template in every page

as

```
<div ng-include src="template.url"></div>
```

Check the jsfiddle for implementing ng-include

http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/MfHa6/